# Code stopped working and I don't get any errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following issue: the `//takedamage` code below was working but when I added the `//respawn` code, it stopped working and I don't get any errors. The rest of the game seems to run fine, its just the `//takedamage` code which doesn't work.

```
//takedamage

public override IEnumerator TakeDamage (){
    health -= 10;

    if (!IsDead) {
        MyAnimator.SetTrigger ("damage");
    } else {
        MyAnimator.SetLayerWeight (1, 0);
        MyAnimator.SetTrigger ("die");
    }
    yield return null;
}

//respawn
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if(other.tag == "FallDetector"){
        transform.position = respawnPoint;

    }
    if (other.tag == "Checkpoint") {
        respawnPoint = other.transform.position;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. I am new to `C#` so any help is welcome.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your post. Can you describe what you expect `OnTriggerEnter2D` to do, and what it actually does now?

Comment: Where have you declared respawnPoint?

Comment: Since `TakeDamage` is a coroutine (it really doesn't need to be, btw), and since your description of the problem is "it stopped working" (a useless description, unless you're talking about the entire program), my guess is that you're getting stuck on an infinite loop of some sort(?)...